# Variable from Input

Tags: powershell

Say I have a list of four different departments

1. Music
2. Science
3. PE
4. Maths

Am I able to set it up so that when you choose the number it stores the department as a variable of `$department`

I want to do a `Write-Host` with a list of all four departments and then a `$department = Read-Host` asking them select a number from 1-4 and it will set the variable as Maths etc.

Any help is appreiciated!

Kind Regards

Comment: Try searching for 'PowerShell Menu with Read-Host'.. There are many, MANY examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Thought Process

This is a pretty textbook problem.  You want to have an array of departments, and then display the array to the user with an integer corresponding to the element's index + 1.

You then receive an integer input from the user corresponding to a department (with a bit of error checking to ensure they enter an integer that actually corresponds to a department) and then use that integer to get the appropriate array element from the departments array.  Since input from `Read-Host` is a string by default, you need to cast `$UserInput` as an `[int]` before using it to get the index of an array.

Again, since we're listing the values to the user using array index + 1, we must consider that when retrieving the array element from the array, hence why we subtract 1 from the value obtained from the user.

## Code

```
# Our array of departments
$Departments = @(
    "Music",
    "Science",
    "PE",
    "Maths"
)

# List each department for the user to pick from, being sure to off-set it's array index by 1
foreach($Department in $Departments){
    Write-Host "$([array]::IndexOf($Departments, $Department) + 1). $Department"
}

# Get the appropriate value that corresponds to a department from the user, retry if user entered invalid value
do {
    $UserInput = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the number corresponding to the desired department"
} while ($UserInput -le 0 -or $UserInput -gt $Departments.Length)

# Once we have a value from the user, use it to assign get the appropriate department, make sure to offset it by 1
$SelectedDepartment = $Departments[[int]$UserInput - 1]
Write-Host "User selected department: $SelectedDepartment"
```

## Example Execution and Output

```
1. Music
2. Science
3. PE
4. Maths
Enter the number corresponding to the desired department: 0
Enter the number corresponding to the desired department: 5
Enter the number corresponding to the desired department: 4
User selected department: Maths
```

Answer (score 2):

Using enums - get you started, no error handling like above

```
enum Department
{
    Music = 1
    Science = 2
    PE = 3
    Maths = 4
}

$Departments = [Department]

Write-Host "Please Select"
Write-Host "-------------"
forEach ($departmentName in $Departments.GetEnumNames())
{
    Write-Host "$departmentName = $(($Departments::$departmentName).value__)"
}

$DepartmentNumber = Read-Host "Please Select a Department number"
$Department = [Department]$DepartmentNumber

Write-Host $Department
```

Output:

```
Please Select
-------------
Music = 1
Science = 2
PE = 3
Maths = 4
Please Select a Department: 3
PE
```

Further reading on enum:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_enum?view=powershell-7.1